# Android ListView onItemClick Event Not Working

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to show some of the blocked SMSes as a list when an OnClick evet occurs. I take the ones I want to show from SharedPreferences and put them in an array. Then I use an Adapter to show them but I get errors at:

```
ArrayAdapter<SMS> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SMS>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smses);
```

and

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
```

and

```
String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
```

I followed the tutorial at http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/handling-android-listview-onitemclick-event this web site.  I can not find what the problem is and there are no suggestions for error lanes.

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showBlockedButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            int total_blocked = preferences.getInt("blocked_size", 0);
            SMS[] smses = new SMS[total_blocked];
            for(int i = 0; i < total_blocked ;i++)
            {
                SMS sms = new SMS(preferences.getString("block_num_"+i, null),preferences.getString("block_body_"+i, null));
                sms.id = i;
                smses[i] = sms;
            }

            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.blockedSMSList);

            ArrayAdapter<SMS> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SMS>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smses);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

                    String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Sorry if my explanation is bad. Thank you!

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: I just get "No suggestions available"  notice at the 3 lanes I mentioned. So the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to change this line**

```
ArrayAdapter < SMS > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < SMS > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smses);
```

**in**

```
ArrayAdapter < SMS > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < SMS > (MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smses);
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem at that lane but the other two still is underlined with red line and there are no suggestions available still. Thank you again